# If condition wont work in 2d array, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Im trying to make my programs control keys depending on the users choice for these 3 controls:

```
(a)         (b)           (c)

0 1 2       1 2 3         7 8 9             
3 4 5       4 5 6         4 5 6             
6 7 8       7 8 9         1 2 3
```

i managed to finish the first two but for my 3rd one (keyboard c) numbers dont seem to come up right they randomly appear instead, what am i dong wrong :(

heres my code:

```
 int main(){
    int r,c,ui,cntr;
    char kb, aray[3][3]={{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'}};

    map(aray);

printf(" Which keyboard method would u prefer? \n");
            scanf("%c", &kb);
    for(cntr=0;cntr<9;cntr++){

        printf("Please play ur next move! \n \n");
        scanf("%i", &ui);
        if(kb=='b'){
            ui--;
        }
        if(kb=='c' && 0<ui &&ui<4){
            ui+=5;
        }
        if(kb=='c' && 3<ui &&ui<7){
            ui--;
        }
        if(kb=='c' && 6<ui &&ui<10){
            ui-=7;
        }

        r=ui/3;
        c=ui%3;
        if(aray[r][c]=='X'){
            printf("Error choose a different spot! \n");
            cntr--;
                }else{
                aray[r][c]='X';
                system("cls");
                map(aray);
                }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably be using if else statements for your keyboard c. Just check what will happen if you hit 1.

Comment: '1' places in the position of '6'

Comment: but i mean it should work without having to put else righht?

Comment: No it wouldn't because after yoiu set it to 6 you check for that range and reduce it by one.

Comment: Oh i Seeeeeeee so it keeps changing the new ui! thaank u soo much for pointing this out!!

Answer (score 0):

Question has been resolved; thanks to Hauke S, i noticed that without else stateement i will keep changing the new ui!